# I want to refactoring my code to get all images at once and map it to its id in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, refactoring

I have two tables the one is Image table and another is Cart table.
When I want to retrieve the carts as list now I am iterating carts and find image by product pk and encode it to string and put it in response.

```
        for (Cart cart : cartList) {
            itemAndQuantityResponses.add(ItemAndQuantityResponse.builder()
                    .image(fileHandler.getStringImage(imageRepository.findByImageRelationAndForeignId(ImageRelation.ITEM_MAIN, cart.getItem().getId())))
                    .build());
        }
```

I thought it is quite inefficient so I decided to refactoring it and the results like this.

```
        final List<Long> itemIds = cartList.stream().map(Cart::getItem).map(Item::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
        final List<Image> images = imageRepository.findByImageRelationAndForeignIdIn(ImageRelation.ITEM_MAIN, itemIds);
        for (ItemAndQuantityResponse itemAndQuantityResponse : itemAndQuantityResponses) {
            for (Image image : images) {
                final String stringImage = fileHandler.getStringImage(image);
                if (itemAndQuantityResponse.getItemId().equals(image.getForeignId())) {
                    itemAndQuantityResponse.setImage(stringImage);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

But either way doesn't look good to me.
If it is possible, I want to avoid to use double for loop as much as I can.

Even a tiny hint would be very helpful for me.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would cache the images in a `Map<Number, Image>` (whether `Image#getForeignId` returns `Number`) first:

```
Map<Number, Image> imageByForeign = images.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Image::getForeignId, Function.identity()));
```

Now you can iterate over the responses and get the images directly. If there can be any responses without a matching image, I would do it like this:

```
for (ItemAndQuantityResponse itemAndQuantityResponse : itemAndQuantityResponses) {
    Optional.of(imageByForeign)
        .map(m -> m.get(itemAndQuantityResponse.getItemId()))
        .map(fileHandler::getStringImage)
        .ifPresent(itemAndQuantityResponse::setImage);
```

If every response's ID is a key in the map just get rid of `Optional`.